# pm2 throws error in git hook

Tags: git, node.js, hook

My Server throws an error if the following git post-receive hook is called:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
pm2 start main.js --name powerapp
```

If the command is entered by one by one into the terminal it will work. So what am I doing wrong?

**Error:**

```
remote: fs.js:642
remote:   return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
remote:                  ^
remote: Error: EACCES, permission denied '/etc/.pm2'
remote:     at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:642:18)
remote:     at Object.CLI.pm2Init (/home/nodejs/.local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/CLI.js:39:8)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nodejs/.local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2:21:5)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
remote:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
remote:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
remote:     at node.js:901:3
```

pm2 was installed via
    npm install pm2 -g
and should run by the user 'git'.

Comment: What is the home directory of the `git` user? Likely it's `/etc`, but that's a bad idea, because no one except `root` should be allowed to create files in there.

Comment: In the terminal echo $HOME tells '/var/opt/gitlab'. But if I try 

    #!/bin/bash
    #
    echo $HOME

in my post-receive hook there is an empty result. Guess I messed something up with my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PM2_HOME='/var/opt/gitlab/.pm2'
```

did it for me. Still wondering if I misconfigured something.